# How to understand the third sentence in the following context? It's from an architecture technical book.

Tags: meaning

Check-barriers provide a means of temporarily controlling the movement of the movement of the public, for example for restricting admission when checking tickets. Rigid check-barriers should not be provided across any gangway or escape route. **Rope and similar barriers should be fitted with automatic catches or slip connections, arranged to part on body pressure and not to trail on the floor when parted; the fittings should not project into the gangway or escape route.**

Comment: Who wrote this book?

Comment: @michael_timofeev a few organizations including The Association of British Theater Technicians.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like stadium walkways and entryways. Humans can crush themselves to death following a concert or sporting event, or in the event of a fire, if the paths are impeded by turnstiles, ropes, fencing, or other barriers. It [getting trapped] happened to me once at Soldier Field in Chicago following a concert--it was terrifying.

Answer (score 1):

The point is to encourage safety.

Rope and similar barriers: *that is, barriers that are not rigid (not stiff)*

should be fitted with: *must have / must be made with*

automatic catches or slip connections, arranged to part on body pressure: *closing mechanisms that don't need to be manipulated by hand to open them; they should open by themselves when a person pushes against the barrier by walking into it*

and not to trail on the floor when parted;: *when the barrier is open, the rope or the other non-rigid barrier material can't trail (drape) onto the floor because that would be a tripping hazard*

the fittings should not project into the gangway or escape route.: *the places where the barriers attach to the wall or any railing must not protrude (must not cause a bump or blockage) into the exit because that will cause a hazard and might slow people down or cause them to fall or be injured if they are pushed against it in a crowd*

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed explanation. It really helps.